# Custom ListView for displaying Contacts takes more time to load

Tags: android, android-contacts, custom-lists, custom-adapter, performance

In my app, when launched I would like to display all the contacts with search filter option. I have achieved this but the problem is - while loading the contacts, it takes more time. How can I improve the efficiency of the code ? Below code snippet shows how I am retreiving contacts:

`public ContactList newContactList(Context ctx)
{`

`ContactList contacts = new ContactList();`

`String id = "";`

`String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";`

`try
        {`

```
    this.cur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, sortOrder);       
    if (this.cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            Contact c = new Contact();
            id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                c.setId(id);
                c.setDisplayName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                c.setPhone(this.getPhoneNumbers(ctx, id));
                c.setEmail(this.getEmailAddresses(id));
                c.setNotes(this.getContactNotes(id));
                c.setAddresses(this.getContactAddresses(id));
                c.setImAddresses(this.getIM(id));
                c.setOrganization(this.getContactOrg(id));
                //c.setPicture(loadContactPhoto(cr, cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID))));
                contacts.addContact(c);
            }               
        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        cur.close();            
    }

    return(contacts);
}
```

ContactList is a class that returns ArrayList of all contacts, and with this arraylist I am setting it to my custom adapter class. I guess, because of fetching arraylist by itereating through cursor is taking much time. But, I would need this arraylist to filter the contacts based on search criteria and to display the custom contact list. Is there any way that I can improve the performance of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use CursorAdapter ?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: Thank you Alexandre for your quick response. I tried using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display contacts and it is loading contacts quickly. But can you guide me how I can implement onClick method on any item in the contact list, which should take ID and display that particular contact details accordingly. Below is the code I used in a ListActivity to display contacts.

Comment: On your ListView, just add the setOnItemClickListener `mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
      long arg3) {
     
    }
   });` and in the onItemClick method, play with your curstom adatper for getting item like `mListView.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);`